Blazor (WA .NET6)- TS1109 Error, how to fix it?
I've been working on a Blazor WebAssembly .NET6 project for a couple of years.
I updated VS2022 recently to the latest 17.10.0(I was in the previous 16.9 before), and after that I'm having TS1109 all over the razor files, my partner also is getting the same errors.

@inject IUserService UserService
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject IDialogService DialogService
...

It is showing TS errors all the time pointing to the first lines of the opened .razor files, which are the @using or @inject lines that have been there since the start of the project.
It allows me to compile and run, but it annoys mee seeing all those errors
I don't know if somoeone else ver here has experienced the same problem, I've tried a few things and nothing helped.
Thanks in advance, and let me know if you need more info.
Tried deleting cache, obj and bin folders. Reinstalling VS2022, and setting the error list to just compilation instead of Intellisense, that last option only hides the error, but also hide other errors that are not TS related.
My partner with the same version and project, and without VS extensions/addons is having the same issue, so it might not be addon related
*Edit: It has been patched and fixed with the 17.10.2 update
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/TS1109-TS-Expression-expected-error-in/10635769

Tried deleting cache, obj and bin folders. Reinstalling VS2022, and setting the error list to just compilation instead of Intellisense, -> maybe we can also try to delete the .vs folder and clean and rebuild the app? .vs folder is a hidden folder. By the way, let's try to upgrade nuget packages to see whether it wored or not. Just make a replication for the csproj file so that we can roll back to origin nuget packages. Normally speaking, upgrade of VS won't cause code compilation issue just like you know...

Did you include the "web development" workload during installation?

I've checked and yes, web development component was there enabled.  About the .vs folder, i've deleted it with vs closed, then reopened and made a cleanup and recompiled, and the errors are still there.

@luhia91 Thanks for your confirmation, and have you tried to upgrade nuget packages?

I am updating the nuget packages one by one, since I am using .net6, some newer packages are giving errors. I'll report after I update the ones I can, but so far the TS1109 errors are still there

Thank you. Just like you know that TS1109 error is a TypeScript error so that this error looks not related to your blazor application. If upgrading Nuget packages doesn't help, we might check whether there's any TypeScript codes in your application, then let's see whether there's any compatibility issue or syntax error.

I found that the issue is being investigated by the VS team and is also happening to more people: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/TS1109-TS-Expression-expected-error-in/10635769

The issue has been fixed by Microsoft with the 17.10.2 Version update today

I have managed to turn off the latest VS2022 17.10.1 Intellisense's TS1109 errors for .razor files by selecting “Only report diagnostics for files opened in the editor” checkbox located in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> Project -> General

Based on a workaround posted in VS Dev community:
Workaround - Maria Solano [MSFT]
Hope this will work for you too - good luck!

This solution worked for me perfectly. Thank you. I asked ChatGPT 4.o and it was clueless. We put too much trust on these LLMs to be honest.

I've solved the issue by disabling TypeScript LSP-based pull diagnostics.
Type Ctrl-Q and enter TypeScript LSP to quickly navigate to the corresponding setting:


Is this the option only available in the preview/beta version? 17.11 Preview1 ?  I am waiting for a realease in the main branch

It's fixed now with the latest 17.10.2 Update, no need for workarounds now

Per @luhia91 the issue is fixed in VS 17.10.2.  No need for workarounds.
Here is a link to the release notes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17102--visual-studio-2022-version-17102

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
